# What happens when we plug a piece of hardware into a computer system?

Tags: windows, linux, operating-system, x86, hardware

When we plug a piece of hardware into a computer system, say a NIC (Network Interface Card) or a sound card, what happens under the hood so that we coud use that piece of hardware?

I can think of the following 2 scenarios, correct me if I am wrong.

- If the hardware has its own memory chips, ***someone*** will arrange for a range of address space to map to those memory chips.
- If the hardware doesn't have its own memory chips, ***someone*** will allocate a range of address in the main memory of the computer system to accomodate that hardware.

I am not sure the aforemetioned ***someone*** is the operating system or the CPU.

And another question: Does hardware always need some ***memory*** to work?

Am I right on this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Better restrict your question to _some_ computer architecture and _some_ OS ...

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. I didn't realize that this could vary among differnt OSes and architectures.

Comment: what sometimes happens, is the magic smoke gets released! ;)

Comment: @Mitch and don't forget the burnout smell ...

Comment: Now, with the scope restricted to windows and linux, this is a valid programming question (perhaps not very well formulated, but valid). How do you program a device driver strategy to automagically recognize and map hardware? ... So I don't understand the votes to close ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The world is not that easily defined.

first off look at the hardware and what it does.  Take a mouse for example, it is trying to deliver x and y coordinate changes and button status, that can be as little as a few bytes or even a single byte two bits define what the other 6 mean, update x, update y, update buttons, that kind of thing.  And the memory requirement is just enough to hold those bytes.  Take a serial mouse there is already at least one byte of storage in the serial port so do you need any more?  usb, another story just to speak usb back and forth takes memory for the messages, but that memory can be in the usb logic, so do you need any more for such small information.

NICs and sound cards are another category and more interesting.  For nics you have packets of data coming and going and you need some buffer space, ring, fifo, etc to allow for multiple packets to be in flight in both directions for efficiency and interrupt latency and the like.  You also need registers, these have their storage in the hardware/logic itself and wont need main memory.  In both the sound card case and the nic case you can either have memory on the board with the hardware or have it use system memory that it can access semi-directly (dma, etc).   Sound cards are similar but different in that you can think of the packets as being fixed sized and continuous.  Basically you need to ping-pong buffers to or from the card at some rate, 44100khz 16 bit per sample stereo is 44100 * 2 * 2 = 176400 bytes per second, say for example the driver/software is preparing the next 8192 bytes at a time and while the hardware is playing the pong buffer software is filling the ping buffer, when hardware drains the pong buffer it indicates this to the software, starts draining the ping buffer and the software fills the ping buffer.

All interesting stuff but to get to the point.  With the nic or sound card you could have as little as two registers, an address/command register and a data register.  Quite painful but was often used in the old days in restricted systems, still used as well.  Or you could go to the other extreme and desire to have all of the memory on the device mapped into system memory's address space as well as each register having its own unique address.  With audio you dont really need random access to the memory so you dont really need this, graphics you do, nic cards you could argue do you leave the packet on the nic or do you make a copy in system memory where you can have a much larger software buffer/ring freeing the hardwares limited buffer/ring.  If on nic then you would want random access, if not then you dont.

For isa/pci/pcie, etc on x86 systems the hardware is usually mapped directly into the processors memory space.  So for 32 bit systems you can address up to 4GB, well even if you have 4GB worth of memory some of that memory you cannot get to because video cards, hardware registers, PCI, etc consume some of that address space (registers or memory or both, whatever the hardware was designed to use).  As distasteful as it may appear to day this is why there was a distiction between I/O mapped I/O and memory mapped I/O on x86 systems, its another address bit if you will.  You could have all of your registers in I/O space and not lose memory space, and map memory into nice neat aligned chunks, requiring less of your ram to be replaced with hardware.  either way, isa had basically vendor specific ways of mapping into the memory space available to the isa bus, jumpers, interesting detection schemes with programmable address decoders, etc.  PCI and its successors came up with something more standard.  When the computer boots (talking x86 machines in general now) the BIOS goes out on the pcie bus and looks to see who is out there by talking to config space that is mapped per card in a known place.  Using a known protocol the cards indicate the desired amount of memory they require, the BIOS then allocates out of the flat memory space for the processor chunks of memory for each device and tells the device what address and how much it has been allocated.  It is certainly possible for the operating system to re-do or override this but typically the BIOS does this discovery for the system and the operating system simply reads the config space on each device which includes the vendor id and device id and then knows how and where to talk to the device.   For this memory space I believe the hardware contains the memory/registers.  For general system memory to dma to/from I believe the operating system and device drivers have to provide the mechanism for allocating that system memory then telling the hardware what address to dma to/from.

The x86 way of doing it with the bios handling the ugly details and having system memory address space and pci address space being the same address space has its pros and cons.  A pro is that the hardware can easily dma to/from system memory because it does not have to know how to get from pcie address space to system address space.  The negative is the case of a 32 bit system where pcie normally consumes up to 1GB of address space and the dram you bought for that hole is not available.  The transition from 32 bit to 64 bit is slow and painful, the bioses and pcie chips are still limiting to the lower 4gig and limiting to 1gb for all the pcie devices, even if the chipset has a 64 bit mode, and this is with 64 bit processors and more than 4gb of ram.  the mmu allowes for fragmented memory so that is not an issue.  Slowly the chipsets and bioses are catching up but it is taking time.

USB. these are serial mostly master/slave protocols.  Like a serial port but bigger and faster and more complicated, and like a serial port both the master and slave hardware need to have ram to store the messages, very much like a nic.  Like a nic, in theory, you can be register based and pull the memory sequentially or have it mapped in to system memory and have random access to it, etc.  Think of it this way, the usb interface can/does sit on a pcie interface even if it is on the motherboard.  A number of devices are pcie devices on your motherboard even if they are not an actual pcie connector with a card.  And they fall into the pcie cagetory of how you might design your interface or who has what memory where.

Some devices like video cards have lots of memory on board, more than is practical or is at least painful to allow all of it to be mapped into pcie memory space at once.  And these would want to use a sliding window type arrangement.  Tell the video card you want to look at address 0x0000 in the video cards address space, but your window may only be 0x1000 bytes (for example) in system/pcie space.  When you want to look at addresses 0x1000 to 0x1FFF in video memory space you write some register to move the window then the same pcie memory space accesses different memory on the video card.

x86 being the dominant architecture has this overlapped pcie and system memory addressing thing but that is not how the whole world works.  Other solutions include having independent system and pcie address spaces, with sliding windows, like the video card problem above, allowing you to have say a 2gb video card mapped flat in pcie space but limiting the window into pcie space to something not painful for the host system.

hardware designs are as varied as software designs.  take 100 software engineers and give them a specification and you may get as many as 100 different solutions.  Same with hardware give them a specification and you may get 100 different pcie designs.  Some standards are in place to limit that, and/or cloning where you want to make a sound blaster compatible card, you dont change the interface, but given the freedom software has the hardware can and will vary and with the number of types of pcie devices (sound, hard disk controllers, video, usb, networking,etc) you will get that many different mixes of registers and addressable memory.

sorry for the long answer, hope this helps.  I would dig through linux and/or bsd sources for device drivers along with programmers reference manuals if you can get access to them, and see how different hardware designs use register and memory space and see what designs are painful for the software folks and what designs are elegant and well done.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It's quite extensive and useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what is the interface of the hardware- is it over USB or PCI-Express? (and there could be others connectivity methods too - USB and PCI-Express are the most common)

- With USB
  The host learns about the newly arrived device by reading the descriptors and loads the appropriate device driver. The device would have presented its ID that is used for Plug n Play. The device is also assigned an address by the Host. Once the device driver kicks-in it configures the device and makes it ready for data transfer. The data transfer is done using IRP, the transfer technique and how the IRPs are loaded depend upon whether the transfer is isochronous data or bulk or other modes.

So to answer your second question - yes the hardware needs some memory to work. The Driver and the USB Host Controller Driver  together setup the Memory on the host for the USB Device - the USB Device Driver then accordingly communicates/drives the device.

- With PCI-Express

It is similar  - sorry I do not have hands on experience with PCI-Express.